# php while-loop- closing div

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to make some kind of pagination system.

Each page has a maximum of 4 elements that came from a DB.

Each page is surronded by a div (div id='p1' class='pagedemo _current'). So I have the following:

```
$i=0;
$pag=0;
$arr = array();

while($rowNews = mysql_fetch_array($rsNews)){
    $i++;
    $arr[$i] = $rowNews;

    if($i%4==1){
       echo "div id='p1' class='pagedemo _current'"
     }

  ...show content...

    if($i%4 ==0 ){
       echo"</div>"; //close the tag of class="pagedemo"
    }

}//end of while
```

This open a div when  the i is 1; 5 ; 9.... and closes when is multiple of 4 (4; 8; 12...)
But I also want to close the div when $i its the last number, ie: If there's only 6 results I want to close the div after the 6th element.

I'm not accomplish it

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to count how many rows are in your mysql result. Then compare it with your iterator.

```
$i=0;
$pag=0;
$arr = array();

$total = mysql_num_rows($rsNews);
while($rowNews = mysql_fetch_array($rsNews)){
    $i++;
    $arr[$i] = $rowNews;

    if($i%4==1){
       echo "div id='p1' class='pagedemo _current'"
     }

  ...show content...

    if($i%4 ==0 || $i == $total){
       echo"</div>"; //close the tag of class="pagedemo"
    }

}//end of while
```

Comment: care for $i == $total, that is only because you do a $i++ at the beginning of the loop. If you use a foreach or so later it will be $i == $total-1. By the way I suggest you heavily to remove the $i++ from the beginning,and update your code to reflect this change. indexes are counted from 0 not 1! If you leave it its kinda misleading for someone else.

Comment: Ah, I agree. But in his case he wanted his rows to start with 1, instead of 0. If I did start with 0, then I would change the $i%4==0 to ($i+1)%4==0.

Comment: ace: actually the comment was for user794035, I though I should advice him how to do it right. I think its bad style to do it so.

Answer (score 2):

just check $i after your loop and close if i%4 != 0 (means is not closed yet)

```
$i=0;
$pag=0;
$arr = array();

while($rowNews = mysql_fetch_array($rsNews)){
    $i++;
    $arr[$i] = $rowNews;

    if($i%4==1){
       echo "div id='p1' class='pagedemo _current'"
     }

  ...show content...

    if($i%4 ==0 ){
       echo"</div>"; //close the tag of class="pagedemo"
    }

}//end of while
if ($i%4 !=0) {
echo"</div>"; //close the tag of class="pagedemo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after your while:

```
if ($i%4 != 0) {
  echo"</div>";
}
```

EDIT: should be like @evildead

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to detect if the close is needed and check at the end:

```
while($rowNews = mysql_fetch_array($rsNews)){
    $i++;
    $arr[$i] = $rowNews;

    if($i%4==1){
       $close = true;
       echo "div id='p1' class='pagedemo _current'"
     }

  ...show content...

    if($i%4 ==0 ){
       $close = false;
       echo"</div>"; //close the tag of class="pagedemo"
    }

}

if($close)
echo"</div>";
```